# amature problem

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

[image]

Im having problems trying to understand rigging and I keep getting this problem. Am I assigning to much on my body which is giving me this problem?

Comment: If your geometry isn't keeping up with your bones, you may need to adjust and strengthen your weight paints. Heres a simple video that should teach you the basics of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl4qTgwQwYw

Comment: Please try to find a specific title, try to decribe your "armature problem" in detail and/or share a blend https://blend-exchange.com/. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're assigning too much on something-- or too little on something, which is really the same thing-- or else something entirely different is going on, such as doubled armature modifiers, who knows?  Look at your actual weights, using the sidebar with an actively selected vertex, or provide a file.

Answer (score 0):

If components are only moving half with certain bones, that means they are part of a different vertex group that is connected to another bone, and blender is averaging out between them. This is very useful to make elbow skin bend gently and not sharp, but it seems as if the whole mesh is assigned to the vertex group of one bone as well as the parts being individually assigned to their correct bones.

Fixing may just be a matter of using automatic weights, or you may need to work out a more fine-tuned solution.